# Long GET request on REST API, handling server crashes

Tags: rest, asynchronous

I have a REST API where the GET request can take 10-20 seconds.  So I usually return a `202` code with a location like http://fakeserver/pending/blah where the client can check the status of this request.  `pending/blah` returns a `200` code with "Status: pending" if the request is still pending, and a `303` code when it's done, with a final location for the result: http://fakeserver/finished/blah .

But what if the server crashes during the request processing? Should `pending/blah` return a `303` code, and then `finished/blah` returns a `404`? How can I alert the client that the resource **may** be available at a location, but I'm not sure? Assume the requests are persistent, so that when the server reboots, it continues processing the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I'll make the state of processed resource an internal field of this resource. This way you can avoid using strange endpoints like: `/finished/blah/` or `/pending/blah/` and instead of it introduce a single endpoint `/resources/blah/` which will among other fields return the state it's currently in.

After changing architecture to the endpoint mentioned above if you ask for `blah` and server has crashed you can:

- return 200 with `pending` status - client doesn't have necessarily to know about the crash
- return 404, simple not found with and extra message that server has crashed.
- return 500 and inform the client explicitly what the problem is.

Other useful codes may be also 409 or 503. Returning any 3XX is not a good idea IMO since no redirection applies here. Personally I'd go for 200 or 500(3).

Comment: @SteveD, did you find my answer useful?